# Jsoup get content from <br>

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to get somehow a phone number from a `<br>` tag that is always below `class` `firmheader`.

```xml
<td class='second' valign='top'>
<div class='firmheader'>Police departament</div>
<br><h2 class='subtitle'>Adress</h2>New Jersey <a class='discret' target='_top' title='See NJ departamant' href='/nj/dep'>NJ</a>, Phone: +160923490434</br>
```

I am tried:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("my_url").get();
Element element = doc.select("br.h2").first();
```

without success.

Comment: Phone is not in any HTML elements you may use regex for this case.

Comment: @uğuraydın there is a `</br>` at the end, sorry for tipo

Answer (score 1):

First get text of nearest outer tag. In your html fragment it is `<td>`. `<br>` tag has no end tag.

```
String address = doc.select("td.second").text();
```

Now you get "Police departament AdressNew Jersey NJ, Phone: +160923490434" text and you need to use regexp for get "Phone" field.